# is there is any sequence fn which satisfies teh given property but does not tends to a limit

Tags: limits

The distance between the consecutive terms of the sequence is strictly decreasing. That is, for all
$n,$
$$|f_{n+2} − f_{n+1}| < |f_{n+1} − f_n|.$$  Is that the sequence $f_n$ will tend to a limit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try $ f_{2n}=1-\frac1{2n}$ and $f_{2n-1}=0$.